# Does `python setup.py test` install dependencies or not?

Tags: python, testing, setuptools

At first it looks like test dependencies are being installed (`Processing coverage-4.4.2-py3.5.egg`) and then all of a sudden they aren't (`The 'coverage' module is not installed`). What's going wrong?

```
(DictORM) 14:15 john@john:~/git/DictORM(master)$ python setup.py test --run-coverage
running green
Searching for coveralls
Best match: coveralls 1.2.0
Processing coveralls-1.2.0-py3.5.egg

Using /home/john/repos/git/DictORM/.eggs/coveralls-1.2.0-py3.5.egg
Searching for coverage
Best match: coverage 4.4.2
Processing coverage-4.4.2-py3.5.egg

Using /home/john/repos/git/DictORM/.eggs/coverage-4.4.2-py3.5.egg
Searching for docopt>=0.6.1
Best match: docopt 0.6.2
Processing docopt-0.6.2-py3.5.egg

Using /home/john/repos/git/DictORM/.eggs/docopt-0.6.2-py3.5.egg
Fatal: The 'coverage' module is not installed.  Have you run 'pip install coverage' ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does.  An import error in this environment was caused by green not actually specifying coverage as an extra dependency.  We decided to just make it a required dependency in 2.12.0 which fixes this issue.  [The bug fix was discussed here](https://github.com/CleanCut/green/issues/174).